# Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in Iterator

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, xml, magento2.3

I'm tryingto extend Magento2 Adminhtml with some custom nodes, which has worked good so far. What I'm trying to do now is to figure out how this error is happening:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 63
```

So basically this issue is coming from malformed XML files that handles my adminhtml.

ACL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Vendor_Module::config" title="Config for Advanced Catalog" sortOrder="100"/>
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <advancedcatalog>
            <general>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
                <debug>0</debug>
            </general>
        </advancedcatalog>
    </default>
</config>
```

system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="advancedcatalog" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" translate="label">
            <label>Advanced Catalog</label>
            <tab>advancedcatalog</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1"
                       showInWebsite="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="debug" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1"
                       showInWebsite="1">
                    <label>Debug Mode</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

However, if I flush and clean cache's I'll get the error message. I do know that this error is coming when there are different IDs, however I cannot  figure out where I made my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to define the Tab I want to display my entities. To do so I just had to update `system.xml` with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="vendor_main_node" translate="label" sortOrder="200">
            <label>Vendor</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="advancedcatalog" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" translate="label">
            <label>Advanced Catalog</label>
            <tab>vendor_main_node</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::config</resource>
            ....
```